# Documenting Cornice's Resources with Cornice's Sphinx integration

Tags: python, pyramid, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, cornice

I have a [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/) application with [Cornice](http://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) package where I defined `Resources` (rather than `Services`) and I wonder if it is possible to generate [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) documentation for this project with a help of [Cornice's Sphinx integration](http://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sphinx.html)?

I managed to generate some sort of documentation but it seems like majority of features are not available for Resources, only for Services, for example, documenting Pyramid code in this way:

```
@resource(collection_path='/parse/', path='/parse/{id}', cors_origins=('*',), description="Temporary description.")
class Parser(object):

    @view(renderer='json')
    def collection_post(self):
        """
        Some description for this function...
        :param str smth: Some parameter
        :return: Returns something
        """
        return
```

and building Sphinx documentation like this:

```
.. cornice-autodoc::
   :modules: my_app.views.views_parser
   :ignore: parser
```

will result in few unnecessary and few missing parts in documentation:

- service names (actually resource names) are messed up,
- function `collection_post` itself is not documented,
- no need to document both `collection_path` and `path` from `resource` declaration):

---

<sub><sup>(example snippet from generated documentation)</sup></sub>

## Collection_Parser service at /parse/

Temporary description.

### POST

**Response: json**

## Parser service at /parse/{id}

Temporary description.

---

What I would like to know is:

- how to change names generated in documentation (`Parser` instead of `Collection_Parser`),
- how to 'ignore' some modules with `:ignore:` statement (e.g. I don't want to document `/parse/{id}` part),
- how to document functions within Resources, since putting a comment block is just being ignored (`collection_post` in my case)

...and many other things...
It seems like this is either impossible or not documented at all. If the case is that this is impossible is there any other (at least semi-automated) solution for documenting my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is not possible because Cornice does not support this kind of functionality (https://github.com/mozilla-services/cornice/issues/279)...